# Portal wont work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so I built an end portal in creative, killed the dragon, but didn't get the egg... Now when I try to build the portal the proper way, it wont activate. Do I need a new profile to do this?

Comment: *"Build it the proper way"* What do you mean by "the proper way"? As in find one in a dungeon and fill all the empty squares with ender eyes?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, a few points to make here.

1. You cannot create an End portal within the End
2. When you kill an Ender Dragon, the egg ALWAYS drops, you just need to find it; or you were so unfortunate that the egg teleported off the End.
3. If your portal will not create in the overworld, try removing the old one you previously created.
4. Try forcefully resetting the End. I'm not familiar with how to do this at the moment, but I'm sure google is.
5. If none of the above works, then try using Ender Eyes to find the real portal, which is located in a "Stronghold." Just right click with the Ender Eye then follow where it goes, until it leads you there. You will know you're there when the Ender Eye floats down when you throw it, rather than up.
6. If any of that didn't work, I suggest create a new world. This one is broken.